# How to parse a complex string with FXSL or equivalent

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, fxsl

I'm new to XSL. Looking here I found the FXSL library that could help solve my problem but I don't know how to go about it.

I have an XML similar to the following one. The application runs an XSL with some external parameters. Within the XML there are some keywords with special meanings:

- {MY_EXT_PAR} : it refers to an external parameter named MY_EXT_PAR.
- {1}, {2}, ... : they refer to external parameters named PAR1, PAR2, ...
- @LINK1(key1), @LINK2(key1,key2) : they are links to a link tag that returns a value (description) related to the given keys. Many links can be defined with a varying number of keys.
- There should be some keywords to format the text (eg. \n for carriage return).

---

Sample XML input:

```
    <Links>
        <Link>
            <Name>LINK1</Name>
            <Element>
                <Key>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Key>
                <Description>Description1</Description>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <Key>
                    <Value>4</Value>
                </Key>
                <Description>Description2</Description>
            </Element>
        </Link>
        <Link>
            <Name>LINK2</Name>
            <Element>
                <Key>
                    <Value>125</Value>
                    <Value>68</Value>
                </Key>
                <Description>Description3</Description>
            </Element>
        </Link>
    </Links>
    <Codes>
        <Code>
            <Description>Connect to external param {MY_EXT_PAR}.\nParameter 1 value is {1} that is @LINK2({2},{3})\n. Parameter 4 value is {4} that is @LINK1({4}).</Description>
        </Code>
    </Codes>
```

---

Are there some examples for this?

Comment: Whoever supplies the XML document is not doing you any favors: you have a *lot* of work to do there. Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509618/string-manipulation-using-xslt-tokenize-and-for-each/20510490#20510490) could help to get you started.

Comment: BTW, the XML you have posted is not well-formed: the `<Codes>` element is not closed, and there is no root element.

Comment: I know, it's a minor part of real xml.

Comment: I don't see the point of the question. What your xslt must do with that input?

Comment: In any case, I believe the best solution lies upstream. Presumably this XML is machine-generated. It should be much easier to program the generating machine **not** to place needles in a haystack than to program another machine to pull them out.

Comment: FXSL's good, but I wouldn't recommend using it if you're new to XSL. To be honest, the `{..}` should really be specified using XML elements. Your quickest solution realistically would be to do a blank text-replace, replacing `{` with `<param>` and `}` with `</param>`, and your XSL suddenly becomes 1000 times easier. Your `@LINK` content could probably be replaced with elements relatively easily with a regex replace.

Comment: Interesting solution. So I should use <param>MY_EXT_PAR</param> and <param>PAR1</param>, ... Linking seems harder because I should replace @LinkName with variable arguments...

Comment: Well, I'd start with a regex, replacing `@LINK(.+?)\((.*?)\)` with `<link name="(capture 1)">(capture 2)</link>`, then do a simple text replace, substituting `{` for `<param>` and `}` for `</param>`. That leaves you with your data in a form that's much easier for .XSL to work with. The parameters to your `@LINK` 'functions' will also be converted to `<param>`s, and your xsl can just ignore the commas inbetween.